# Will Oculus controllers work on PS3?

Tags: ps3, oculus-rift

The PS3 can support a ton of controllers, even ones that are meant for **newer consoles.** But do oculus controllers work with the PS3? Considering their bluetooth, I see this as a strange, but slightly passable idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it wrong: many controllers support PS3 compatibility, not the other way around. Oculus was never designed with PS3 or even PlayStation compatibility at all. It is supposed to be used on a PC, because consoles don't have the processing power (at least, in the past) to support VR.

To answer your question: no, unfortunately.

Comment: :[ thanks man….

Answer (score 1):

> The PS3 can support a ton of controllers, even ones that are meant for newer consoles

This is true, as long as they have PS3, PS4 or PS5 compatibility (the later two since PS3 System Software update 4.60).

> But do oculus controllers work with the PS3?

They don't work with the PS3, as they don't have a compatibility mode for PS3/4/5.